# error 1054 unknown column in 'on clause' - inner join as view

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1054

Sorry, I'm a newbee here and can't get everyhing right at one time in beautiful code lists. I'm in a prephase to (let) launch my database on a website, but before I do I need to create a (total) view with inner join. And i get a message of the infamous 1054 unknown column in 'on clause'. Here is the actual MySQL script. Can someone help me succeeding the script as a view ? Around this code in the script it stucks (**between the stars in the FROM SYNTAX**): INNER JOIN zorgaanbieder AS zorgaanbieder_1 ON (**zorgverlener.Zorgaanbieder_ID** = zorgaanbieder_1.Zorgaanbieder_ID). Please see code below

```
CREATE VIEW `fetch_data` AS

SELECT
    zorgactiviteiten.ZA_code,
    zorgactiviteiten.ZA_naam,
    zorgactiviteiten.ZA_omschr_consument,
    zorgprofielklasse.ZPK_oms,
    behandelingen.Behandeling_criteria,
    aanspraak.Aanspraak_omschr,
    aanspraak.Aanspraak_machtiging,
    cluster.Cluster_naam,
    diagnosen.Diagnose_code,
    diagnosen.Diagnose_naam,
    diagnosen.Diagnose_groep,
    diagnosen.Diagnose_hoofdstuk,
    specialisme.Specialisme_naam,
    zorgproducten.ZP_code,
    zorgproducten.ZP_naam,
    zorgproducten.ZP_omschr_consument,
    zorgproductgroepen.ZPG_naam,
    declaratie.Declaratie_code,
    declaratie.Declaratie_zorg,
    contractueel.Contractueel_uitleg,
    contract.Contract_zorg,
    contract.Contract_verzekerd,
    contract.Contract_uitsluiting,
    zorgverzekeraar.Zorgverzekeraar_verzekeraar,
    zorgverzekeraar.Zorgverzekering_verzekering,
    zorgverzekeraar.Zorgverzekering_soort,
    zorgverzekeraar.Zorgverzekering_zorgkeuze,
    concern.Concern_inkoop,
    concern.Concern_label,
    zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_plaats,
    zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_regio,
    zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_soort,
    zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_informatie,
    zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_website,
    zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_reviews,
    zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_rapport,
    zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_oordeel,
    zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_prijslijst,
    prijslijst.Prijslijst_tarief,
    prijslijst.Prijslijst_actie,
    prijslijst.Prijslijst_soort,
    prijslijst.Prijslijst_jaar
FROM
    concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst
INNER JOIN
    prijslijst ON (concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst.Prijslijst_ID = prijslijst.Prijslijst_ID)
INNER JOIN
    concern ON (concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst.Concern_ID = concern.Concern_ID)    
INNER JOIN
    zorgaanbieder ON (concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst.Zorgaanbieder_ID = zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_ID)
INNER JOIN
    zorgaanbieder AS zorgaanbieder_1 ON (zorgverlener.Zorgaanbieder_ID = zorgaanbieder_1.Zorgaanbieder_ID)
INNER JOIN
    zorgverlener ON (contract.Zorgverlener_koppel = zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_ID)
INNER JOIN
    concern AS concern_1 ON (zorgverzekeraar.Concern_ID = concern_1.Concern_ID)
INNER JOIN
    zorgverzekeraar ON (contract.Zorgverzekeraar_koppel = zorgverzekeraar.Zorgverzekeraar_ID)
INNER JOIN
    contract ON (contractueel_contract.Contract_ID = contract.Contract_ID)
INNER JOIN
    contractueel_contract ON (contractueel.Contractueel_ID = contractueel_contract.Contract_ID)
INNER JOIN
    contractueel ON (contractueel_decaratie.Contractueel_ID = contractueel.Contractueel_ID)
INNER JOIN
    contractueel_decaratie ON (declaratie.Declaratie_code = contractueel_decaratie.Declaratie_code)
INNER JOIN
    declaratie ON (zorgproducten_declaratie.Declaratie_code = declaratie.Declaratie_code)
INNER JOIN
    zorgproducten_declaratie ON (zorgproducten.ZP_code = zorgproducten_declaratie.ZP_code)
INNER JOIN
    zorgproductgroepen ON (zorgproducten.ZPG_code = zorgproductgroepen.ZPG_code)
INNER JOIN
    zorgproducten ON (dbc.ZP_code = zorgproducten.ZP_code)
INNER JOIN
    specialisme ON (diagnosen.Specialisme_code = specialisme.Specialisme_code)
INNER JOIN
    diagnosen ON (diagnosebereik.Diagnose_ID = diagnosen.Diagnose_ID)
INNER JOIN
    diagnosebereik ON (dbc_diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam = diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam)
INNER JOIN
    dbc_diagnosebereik ON (diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam = dbc_diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam)
INNER JOIN
    dbc ON (dbc_diagnosebereik.DBC_koppel = dbc.DBC_koppel)
INNER JOIN
    behandelingen ON (dbc.DBC_koppel = behandelingen.DBC_koppel)
INNER JOIN
    cluster ON (behandelingen.Cluster_ID = cluster.Cluster_ID)
INNER JOIN
    aanspraak ON (behandelingen.Aanspraak_code = aanspraak.Aanspraak_code)
INNER JOIN
    zorgactiviteit_behandelingen ON (behandelingen.Behandeling_naam = zorgactiviteit_behandelingen.Behandeling_naam)
INNER JOIN
    zorgactiviteiten ON (zorgactiviteit_behandelingen.ZA_code = zorgactiviteiten.ZA_code)
INNER JOIN
    zorgprofielklasse ON (zorgactiviteiten.ZPK_code = zorgprofielklasse.ZPK_code)
```

Comment: Please can you check that there is a column named Zorgaanbieder_ID in the zorgverlener table?

Comment: Looked upon it with statement in Mysql: SELECT Zorgaanbieder_ID
FROM zorgverlener and it gives results. Maybe as you can see I have two inner joins (table zorgaanbieder and concern) with an alias (_1), because else the function would give another error (not unique). It was advised by a collegue of mine (he is a query builder in hospital I work in). The '(...)' behind ON was my job ;-) Was one of the stategies according to MySQL user guide. Hope you can figger it out and glad to have such fast reply. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. What did your extensive googling turn up?

Comment: Thanks for the help Philipxy ! I think you're right. My googling finally turn up I had to register sooner at stackoverflow ;-) ! I believe it's so specific relying on ordering by correct joins and using aliases, but I now know in what direction I have to work. Plenty of advises and try to experiment this weekend and next week. I'll read the example thoroughly and try to build to the last code example. What do you mean with recursive as the problem ? Should I try to merge these 2 lines (tables diagnosebereik and dbc_diagnosebereik) ? I didn't think about that in earlier stage. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Debugging advice: Start small, test, then by grow by small increments and re-test.

I believe you problem is INCORRECT SEQUENCE of joins, NOT incorrect column references. e.g.

```
## this will fail
select a.* from a 
join c on b.id = c.id ## c attempts to join to b = incorrect sequence of joins
join b on a.id = b.id
```

Below, table `zorgverlener` attempts to join to `contract` but it has not yet been joined.

```
SELECT
      czp.*
FROM concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst as czp
...
INNER JOIN zorgverlener ON (contract.Zorgverlener_koppel = zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_ID)
...
INNER JOIN contract ON (contractueel_contract.Contract_ID = contract.Contract_ID)
```

Other tips:

1. Do use table aliases
2. Don't use unnecessary parentheses

To correct that issue change the order of the joins:

```
SELECT
      czp.*
FROM concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst as czp
...
INNER JOIN contract AS C ON contractueel_contract.Contract_ID = contract.Contract_ID
...
INNER JOIN zorgverlener ON c.Zorgverlener_koppel = zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_ID
```

but now we see that `contractueel_contract` needs to go above contract and so on it goes.

I believe a more correct sequence of jois is as follows, but there are 2 joins I cannot solve:

```
SELECT
      czp.*
FROM concern_zorgaanbieder_prijslijst AS czp
INNER JOIN prijslijst ON czp.Prijslijst_ID = prijslijst.Prijslijst_ID
INNER JOIN concern ON czp.Concern_ID = concern.Concern_ID

## problems in the next 2 lines, seem to be recursve
INNER JOIN diagnosebereik ON dbc_diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam = diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam
INNER JOIN dbc_diagnosebereik ON diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam = dbc_diagnosebereik.Diagnosebereik_naam

INNER JOIN dbc ON dbc_diagnosebereik.DBC_koppel = dbc.DBC_koppel
INNER JOIN zorgproducten ON dbc.ZP_code = zorgproducten.ZP_code
INNER JOIN zorgproducten_declaratie ON zorgproducten.ZP_code = zorgproducten_declaratie.ZP_code
INNER JOIN declaratie ON zorgproducten_declaratie.Declaratie_code = declaratie.Declaratie_code
INNER JOIN contractueel_decaratie ON declaratie.Declaratie_code = contractueel_decaratie.Declaratie_code
INNER JOIN contractueel ON contractueel_decaratie.Contractueel_ID = contractueel.Contractueel_ID
INNER JOIN contractueel_contract ON contractueel.Contractueel_ID = contractueel_contract.Contract_ID
INNER JOIN contract ON contractueel_contract.Contract_ID = contract.Contract_ID
INNER JOIN zorgverlener ON contract.Zorgverlener_koppel = zorgverlener.Zorgverlener_ID
INNER JOIN zorgaanbieder ON czp.Zorgaanbieder_ID = zorgaanbieder.Zorgaanbieder_ID
INNER JOIN zorgaanbieder AS zorgaanbieder_1 ON zorgverlener.Zorgaanbieder_ID = zorgaanbieder_1.Zorgaanbieder_ID
INNER JOIN zorgverzekeraar ON contract.Zorgverzekeraar_koppel = zorgverzekeraar.Zorgverzekeraar_ID
INNER JOIN concern AS concern_1 ON zorgverzekeraar.Concern_ID = concern_1.Concern_ID
INNER JOIN zorgproducten_declaratie ON zorgproducten.ZP_code = zorgproducten_declaratie.ZP_code
INNER JOIN zorgproductgroepen ON zorgproducten.ZPG_code = zorgproductgroepen.ZPG_code
INNER JOIN diagnosen ON diagnosebereik.Diagnose_ID = diagnosen.Diagnose_ID
INNER JOIN specialisme ON diagnosen.Specialisme_code = specialisme.Specialisme_code
INNER JOIN behandelingen ON dbc.DBC_koppel = behandelingen.DBC_koppel
INNER JOIN cluster ON behandelingen.Cluster_ID = cluster.Cluster_ID
INNER JOIN aanspraak ON behandelingen.Aanspraak_code = aanspraak.Aanspraak_code
INNER JOIN zorgactiviteit_behandelingen ON behandelingen.Behandeling_naam = zorgactiviteit_behandelingen.Behandeling_naam
INNER JOIN zorgactiviteiten ON zorgactiviteit_behandelingen.ZA_code = zorgactiviteiten.ZA_code
INNER JOIN zorgprofielklasse ON zorgactiviteiten.ZPK_code = zorgprofielklasse.ZPK_code
```

Comment: Sorry Used_By_Already. Answer above was ment as comment to you, but added comment wrong. I believe close to solve with coding. I merged the problem lines (tables diagnosebereik and dbc_diagnosebereik) into table 'dbc_diagnosen'. So code from your statement is: "## problems...INNER JOIN dbc_diagnosen ON diagnosen.Diagnose_ID = dbc_diagnosen.Diagnose_ID
INNER JOIN dbc ON dbc_diagnosen.DBC_koppel = dbc.DBC_koppel". And later on..."INNER JOIN diagnosen ON dbc_diagnosen.Diagnose_ID = diagnosen.Diagnose_ID" is where I bump into another error 1054 unknown column diagnosen.Diagnose_ID. What's next?

Comment: I noticed that exact same table INNER JOIN zorgproducten_declaratie in your statement was named twice. I deleted the most below to apply in MySql. I like to update the code from the FROM statement that I have at this moment, but don't know how (to less characters left to put code as comment)

Comment: The intent of my answer is to show you why you had the problem and to suggest how to solve it. Bur only you can test any version of the query.  It really is up to you now.  Remember while debugging to start small and add in small increments.